# <button> extra padding problem in Safari

Tags: html, css, button, safari, padding

The sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Button test</title>
    <style>
      * { border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

      body { padding: 5em; }

      span { background: lightblue; display: inline-block; }

      button { background: red; outline: 1px solid red }
      button div { background: yellow; }

      button::-moz-focus-inner {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
      button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -webkit-box-align: start;
        -webkit-border-fit: lines;
        -webkit-margin-collapse: discard;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span>Adjacent text</span><button><div>Button</div></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the image:

[image]

You can see the extra white padding in the button. Is it possible to get rid of that padding in Safari browser?

Comment: You could use ANCHOR's to simulate buttons. [Anchors don't have such styling problems](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/jjCQ4/)

Comment: See my reply to the similar suggestion below.

Comment: Have your tried using a CSS reset sheet?
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Comment: Yes I did. It won't help as well. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in some version of Safari, I'm not sure what exactly, but in latest (5.1.5) it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party but I found over-riding it the webkit border fit with:

`-webkit-border-fit:border !important;`

worked a treat for me.  Esspecially useful for Magento where `webkit-border-fit` property comes in handy at times but can cause problems for certain `<button>`'s.

Comment: Nah, doesn't work, too. In the Safari version I tested it back then. In the latest version it's fixed thought and works as it is.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Worked for me in Chrome (latest as of date of this comment), but only with the addition of `!important`.  Okay, so it seems this still hasn't been solved.  Is this a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS from [The Filament Group](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_styling_the_button_element_with_css_sliding_doors_now_with_image_spr/) has worked for me in all browsers for some time now. The base of the CSS, to strip buttons of all their styling is as follows:

The `span` is used for the sliding-doors technique (better than the `div` you are currently using, this could be a problem), a full style listing can be found via the link.

```
button { 
    position: relative;
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none; /* for good measure */
    overflow: visible; /* removes extra side padding in IE */
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;  /* overrides extra padding in Firefox */
}

button span { 
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    white-space: nowrap;    
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* Safari and Google Chrome only - fix margins */
    button span {
        margin-top: -1px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downside of targeting entire browser (not version lower than some number) is that when the bug will be fixed in browser, `margin-top: -1px` will get causing _undesired_ offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
button { background: red; outline: 1px solid red, position: fixed; }
```

To fix the issue of extra padding in Chrome & Safari. you will have to specify `position: fixed`, this solved the problem for me. hope it will work for you guys too!

Comment: Tried it but that munted the button width/height (and border stuffed up). Using iOS5. Also tried `-webkit-appearance: none;` but that didn't help either.

Answer (score -1):

Form elements such as `<button>` are usually implemented/drawn as a native OS control, so they can look and behave differently in different browsers. If you want complete control over  styling, you'd be better off using an `<a>` tag.

Comment: I would like it to send a form with "POST" HTTP method, and it should work in the user-agents with no JS support.

Comment: @d.m: I'm out of ideas in that case -- it's a difficult requirement especially when considering form elements. Hopefully somebody else can come up with a hack for Safari.

Comment: @dmedvinsky: You can replace `button` elements with links via JS so that non-JS-capable users will see just slightly understyled native button which is generally perfectly acceptable: if rare user has disabled JS, he is already ready for some inconsistencies.